# jQuery Text Highlighting - Multiple Highlights

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, highlight

Using a plugin written by Johann Burkard for highlighting strings of text:

[Higlighting jQuery Plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

I have modified this slightly to accept values from two input fields which will be highlighted when the function is run, however the plugin only allows one colour to be used. Has anyone an idea if there is an extension or know of a way I can extend this further to accept a different highlighting colour?

My code for this:

```
$(function() { 
if ( $("input#searchterm").val().length > 0 ) {
    var arrayOfKeyWords= $("input#searchterm").val().split(',');
    for (var i=0;i<arrayOfKeyWords.length;i++) {
        $('.message p.messagecontent').highlight(arrayOfKeyWords[i]);
    }
}   
if ( $("input#anysearchterm").val().length > 0 ) {
    var arrayOfKeyWords= $("input#anysearchterm").val().split(',');
    for (var i=0;i<arrayOfKeyWords.length;i++) {
        $('.message p.messagecontent').highlight(arrayOfKeyWords[i]);
    }
}       
});
```

This works fine and adds a css class around the strings I would like to highlight so my questions is it possible to specify the class name that will be wrapped around the text in my individual functions so I can then set the colour in CSS?

Plugin source:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight=function(b){function a(e,j){var l=0;if(e.nodeType==3){var k=e.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(j);if(k>=0){var h=document.createElement("span");h.className="highlight";var f=e.splitText(k);var c=f.splitText(j.length);var d=f.cloneNode(true);h.appendChild(d);f.parentNode.replaceChild(h,f);l=1}}else{if(e.nodeType==1&&e.childNodes&&!/(script|style)/i.test(e.tagName)){for(var g=0;g<e.childNodes.length;++g){g+=a(e.childNodes[g],j)}}}return l}return this.each(function(){a(this,b.toUpperCase())})};jQuery.fn.removeHighlight=function(){return this.find("span.highlight").each(function(){this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;with(this.parentNode){replaceChild(this.firstChild,this);normalize()}}).end()};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better to modify the non-minified source.

Comment: Very basically, you could pass in a highlight class to the main function, change the `h.className="highlight";` line to use that variable, and also pass in the highlight class name to `.removeHighlight()`, changing `.find("span.highlight")` to use the passed in class name after `span.`.